# jQuery .last().hide().fadeIn() fading in all items in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

```
$('#mainlist').last().hide().fadeIn(200);
```

Why is this hiding, and then fading in all the items in the list instead of just the last one?

Edit:  The section of HTML:

```
<div id="mainbox">
    <ul id = "mainlist">

    </ul>
</div>
```

My js appends to the ul with a li, and then it runs the first code shown above.

Comment: Mind adding your HTML code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there's only one element in the list returned by `$("#mainlist")`. You're selecting the last `#mainlist` which is your `ul`.

The `.last()` method selects the last element in a list of DOM elements, not the last child of the elements selected.

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/last/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .last() method constructs a new jQuery object from the last element in
>   that set.

You want something like `$('#mainlist li').last().hide().fadeIn(200);` instead.

Comment: Hats off to Mr Beavis!

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `#mainlist` element has another child/wrapping `<ul>` before the list items (so it's hiding the wrapping `<ul>`, thus all the elements). Maybe try be more specific with your selector

```
$("#mainlist li").last().hide().fadeIn(200);
```

**EDIT** By the way, this assumes your `<ul>` is filled with `<li>` tags.